# How to change from onclick to onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this for the preview of a saved HTML code (also live)
But for the 1st time I have to click and enter to view the preview

How can I see preview once the browser window opens?

**Code:**

```
function showHTML () { 
    textarea1 = document.getElementById('htmltxt'); 
    viewHtml = document.getElementById('htmlpreview'); 
    viewHtml.innerHTML = textarea1.value ; 
}
```

Comment: where is your html

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your function when the document loads, as well as in your click handler:

```
function showHTML() {
    textarea1 = document.getElementById('htmltxt');
    viewHtml = document.getElementById('htmlpreview');
    viewHtml.innerHTML = textarea1.value;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showHTML)
```

Note that instead of attaching a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, you could just call `showHTML()` somewhere inside a `<script>` tag that sits after both your `#htmltxt` textarea and your `#htmlpreview` element (so that they will have been parsed before execution begins).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood the requirement is to call showHTML() on page load..

```
<body onload="showHTML()">
<textarea id="htmltxt">
 aksjdhkasjdhakjds
</textarea>
<span id="htmlpreview"></span>
<script>
function showHTML() {
textarea1 = document.getElementById('htmltxt');
viewHtml = document.getElementById('htmlpreview');
viewHtml.innerHTML = textarea1.value;
}
</script>
</body>
```